# Javascript wont fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying out this javascript slip scroll effect, an image changes color when an object scrolls over it and i have all the code exactly the same as the tutorial, except the javascript won't fire? 
[This is the tutorial I used.](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-give-your-logo-the-slip-scroll-effect--cms-22274)
Here's the html I've got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slip Scroll</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>




<div class="container dark">
<img src="images/logogreen.svg" class="default" height="200px">
</div>


<div class="container light">
<img src="images/logopink.svg" class="moveable" height="200px">
</div>


<div class="container dark">
<img src="images/logogreen.svg" class="moveable" height="200px">
</div>



 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slipScroll.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's the javascript im using:

```
var setLogo = function() {

  $('.moveable').each(function() {
    $(this).css('top',
      $('.default').offset().top -
      $(this).closest('.container').offset().top
    );
  });

};

$(document).scroll(function() {
  setLogo();
});

setLogo();
```

Comment: You are missing your `px` from top css. Also, be sure to run it after window load

Comment: You are missing PX in top and why not using .parent() instead of closest()

Comment: What does the console say F12

Comment: Missing px can't cause a problem here. On `top`-property (and many others) jQuery internally adds 'px' to a number value.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('.default').offset().top - $(this).closest('.container').offset().top + 'px'
```

On this line you are trying to

Int- int + string

This could cause the problem so would need to be:

```
        ($('.default').offset().top - $(this).closest('.container').offset().top).toString + 'px'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your css?

UPDATED with background colors -  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/dhojgc8f/)

```
 .dark { 
  background: #333;
 }

.light {
 background: #fff;
 }

.container {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 min-height: 500px;
padding: 1em;
}
.default {
position: fixed;
}

.moveable {
 position: absolute;
}
```